# Health insurance for German citizen student without EHIC

Tags: health-insurance, german-citizens, ehic

I am a German citizen who has been living abroad and never had a health insurance in Germany. 
Until now I lived in a non-European country, so my current health insurance cannot join EHIC.

I am a student in the Netherland, and my question is how can I register to the German health insurance so I will be eligible for EHIC while I am in the Netherlands?

Comment: Maybe you should just register for health insurance in the Netherlands, since that is where you actually reside.  To get a German EHIC card, I believe you will need a registered residence in Germany.

Comment: EHIC is a card. (From your use of the term in this question, I wasn’t sure you are aware of that. In particular, “joining EHIC” makes no sense at all.)

Comment: Since the social laws are based on country laws, it should be **obivous** that a heath service company (Krankenkasse) will only accept members from withing the country it works in.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. German health insurance requires you to have a residence in Germany. If you are a student in the Netherlands and not a resident in Germany, you must get health insurance in the Netherlands.